# Relationship problems in DML/SOQL

Tags: soql, custom-object, query, relationships, nested

I am unable to understand relationships with DML/SOQL.

Example, I have custom objects `Course__c` and `Course_line_item__c`. `Course_line_item__c` has a lookup field on it that points to `Course__c`. So this means multiple `Course_line_item__c`'s can have the same parent `Course__c`, correct?

So I have this SOQL Query :

`list<Course__c> LC=[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Course_line_item__c) FROM Course__c];`

and I'm getting this lovely error :

> Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Course_line_item__c' in
>   FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
>   relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names. at line 13 column 12

What am I doing wrong???

**EDIT :** me custom relationship field is called `CourseLU__c`.

Comment: Use the Child Relationship Name instead of the child object api name.

Comment: eg, `[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CourseLU__c) FROM Course__c]`? `CourseLU__c` is the name of the custom lookup relationship field on the line item to `Course__c`. Crossing my fingers. **EDIT** : nope, I donot understand how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message saying, the relationship name you are using is incorrect. `__r` is used for custom relationships in salesforce(`Course_line_item__r`); and plural form of the object when refer to child object. It should be something like below.

```
list<Course__c> LC=[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Course_line_items__r) FROM Course__c];
```

Make sure you get the correct relationship name. You can refer to your WSDL for this if you are not sure.

Comment: WTF why does your statement work??? this is one of my previous attempts : `list<Course__c> LC=[SELECT Count__c,Fees__c,Id,Name,User__c, (SELECT Attended__c,Course__c,Name,Name__c FROM Course_line_item__r WHERE Course_line_item__r.Course__c.ID=:cid) FROM Course__c WHERE ID=:cid];`. How come YOURS worked and mine didnt?  **EDIT:** barebones version : `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Course_line_item__r WHERE Course_line_item__r.Course__c.ID = :cid) FROM Course__c WHERE ID =: cid`

Comment: If it didn't work, that means that we have some mistake. Compilers, interpreters doesn't have favors for anyone, they works as they are developed. I think you had missed the plural format(**s** at the end) in your sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to share how to find the child relationship name yourself via `Execute Anonymous`:

```
for (ChildRelationship relationship : SObjectType.Course__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relationship.getChildSobject() == Course_Line_Item__c.sObjectType)
         system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName());
```

The above will yield the verbatim name you should use in your subquery, which would then look like:

```
(SELECT Id FROM Course_Line_Items__r)
```